# Linux netlink mutlicast routing updates

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming, multicast, netlink

My application should get netlink multicast route updates from kernel.
I did some research and found mutlicast uses different family:RTNL_FAMILY_IPMR
and group is RTMGRP_IPV4_MROUTE.

However if I use:

```
    sfd = socket (AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_ROUTE);
    snl.nl_groups |= RTMGRP_IPV4_MROUTE
```

I dont get any updates.

But

```
    sfd = socket (AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_ROUTE);
    snl.nl_family = RTNL_FAMILY_IPMR;
    snl.nl_groups |= RTMGRP_IPV4_MROUTE;
```

This give bind error", bind: Invalid argument

```
    sfd = socket (RTNL_FAMILY_IPMR, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_ROUTE);
```

This give "Address family not supported by protocol" error

I'm not sure how to get updates from kernel for mutlicast routes.

Answer (score 0):

copy-paste from earlier project I have:

```
    struct sockaddr_nl naddr;

    netlinkfd = socket (AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_ROUTE);
    naddr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
    naddr.nl_groups = (1 << (RTNLGRP_LINK - 1)) |
                      (1 << (RTNLGRP_IPV4_ROUTE - 1)) |
                      (1 << (RTNLGRP_IPV6_ROUTE - 1)) |
                      (1 << (RTNLGRP_IPV4_IFADDR - 1)) |
                      (1 << (RTNLGRP_IPV6_IFADDR -1 ));
    if (bind (netlinkfd, (struct sockaddr *)&naddr, sizeof (naddr)))
    {
        error_foo();
        return;
    }
```

This one works for me receiving link, ip and routing table in general. (pushing me all the changes from this point of - if I want to receive the current status, I need to request them aswell). Try to have both ROUTE and MROUTE since you want multicast routing tables, but they might be merged into the normal routing table